# Make ConEmu scroll slower

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, conemu

Is there some way to make ConEmu scroll more slowly?

I use touchpad gestures to scroll, and when even when I try to make the smallest possible motion to scroll, conemu will invariably skip 5-6 lines. This makes it very difficult for me to read console output, since it becomes next to impossible to aim without manually clicking and dragging the scrollbar. In contrast, Powershell/regular cmd/every single other program I use will scroll about 1 line whenever I make the same motion, which makes them much more useable.

I tried looking at the "appearance" section, but it only contained options to hide/show the scrollbar.

I also saw several questions on SuperUser which were about disabling the scrollbar in ConEmu, but that's not what I want either.

Running `ConEmu /log` produced the following logfiles:

- [ConEmuC64-size-6768.log](http://pastebin.com/iHgi4zMJ)
- [ConEmu-gui-5364.log](http://pastebin.com/icycV66q)
- [ConEmu-input-6768.log](http://pastebin.com/Mp0TsNGq)

Comment: Run `ConEmu /log`, do your touchpad scroll, show created logfiles.

Comment: @Maximus -- added links to the logfiles in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set up GuiMacro for `Wheel Down` and `Wheel Up`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That did the trick. I had to set the macro to `WheelDown + Win` and `WheelUp + Win` for some reason, but other then that, it worked perfectly. It still scrolls a little faster then usual, but it's definitely a lot more controllable now.